# I have stuck with the simplest SQL query in java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, select

I can't find the correct syntax of the following query in java,please help me.

```
String st = "SELECT COUNT('"+id+"') FROM '"+selected_table+"' ";

String st = "SELECT COUNT('"+id+"') FROM '"+selected_table+"'";
```

I think that the mistake is how to end the query...

Since I got the error Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Customer'' at line 1

when I choose Customer table

Comment: Be careful with forming queries by concatenating strings that originate from the client since that opens up an injection vulnerability.

Comment: @Hyangelo, +1 for good point, but you think (given the implications from the quality of the question) that OP would understand the importance of that?

Comment: @mre good point as well but just felt I had to at least point out the potential danger.

Comment: and in case the OP doesn't know what exactly you mean: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection

Comment: since I am beginner , can you give some tips ,e.g which is the best way to combine Java code with SQL statements

Comment: @user1552812 look up prepared statements. Basically, you create a `PreparedStatement` where in your SQL string, you have `?` stand in for a parameter. Then you call `preparedStatement.setString(1, userInput)` or whatever. Then you execute the statement.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use backticks instead of single quotes around your object names.

```
String st = "SELECT COUNT(`"+id+"`) FROM `"+selected_table+"` ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Table names should be surrounded by tick marks (`), not single quotes (`'`)

```
String st = "SELECT COUNT('"+id+"') FROM `"+selected_table+"`";
                                         ^ use tick marks   ^
```

Answer (score 0):

What are the values of `id` and `selected_table`? What is the actual query string that is sent to the database?

Also, it's rarely a good idea to manually build a query like this using string concatenation. This makes it very easy for a bug to result in a gaping security hole, and it's a lot more difficult (and risky) to try to secure this approach than it is to just do it right.

Comment: Both of the values are String

Comment: That's their *type* – but what would you expect their *values* to be?

Answer (score 0):

Looks from your query that you are enclosing your id and selected_table in single quotes... For example, `SELECT COUNT('ID') FROM 'CUSTOMER'` which is wrong.  should be in backtics `` or nothing...

Comment: Ok it works, in the FROM clause I use "+selected_table+" without ' ' and it works. Thank you very much guys.